# MySQL - Select row only if at least one of values not null or empty

Tags: mysql

It's probably very basic issue but I can't find solution for it. I need to select records where at least one of the values is not 0 or empty. I check 3 columns.

My code:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE datestamp>='$startdate' AND datestamp<='$finishdate'
      AND ((h1col !='' OR h1col !='0') OR  (h2col !='' OR h2col !='0')
                     OR (h3col !='' OR h3col !='0'))");
```

Can you please put me on the right track. Thank you. Always willing to learn. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, just need to use `and` in some places instead of `or`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE datestamp>='$startdate' 
    AND datestamp<='$finishdate' 
    AND ((h1col !='' AND h1col !='0') OR 
         (h2col !='' AND h2col !='0') OR 
         (h3col !='' AND h3col !='0'))
```

Comment: or shorter... `AND ( h1col NOT IN ('','0') OR h2col NOT IN ('','0') OR ...`

Comment: both suggestion worked. I opted for the one of @spencer7593 as being shorter. Good one thank you very much. I already know I will be using "NOT IN" elsewhere too.